# Peer-to-peer networking with ethernet

Tags: networking, pi-3b+, ethernet, p2p, pi-400

I had an idea for transferring data between Pi's. It involves directly connecting two Pi's to each other only using a single cat5 ethernet cable, and transferring data in a peer to peer manner. I have a Model 3B+ and a Model 400, both running Buster. Is there any software that I could use to make this work?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is very straight forward; I have a Pi4 wired to my desktop this way.  The most significant issue would be whatever networking daemon(s) you have running getting in the middle of things.  If you are using the RpiOS default `dhcpcd`, add to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` on both Pi's:

```
denyinterfaces eth0
```

This just tells it to not do anything with this.

You need to decide on a [private address range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Private_addresses_2) to use. Something in `10.x.x.x` is normal here since it is big enough to prevent conflicts, and most inet routers use `192.168.x.x` anyway.  The CIDR suffix can be `/30`, since two bits can have four different values and you only need two (pretty sure you could use `/31` and having one as `10.x.x.0` in this context, but that is not a good practice).

On one Pi:<sup>1</sup>

```
sudo ip link set eth0 up
sudo ip addr add 10.100.0.1/30 dev eth0
```

On the other:

```
sudo ip link set eth0 up
sudo ip addr add 10.100.0.2/30 dev eth0
```

Hopefully the difference is clear. The kernel should automagically set a route when this is done -- check with `ip route`, the output should include:

```
10.100.0.0/30 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.100.0.1
```

The last address should be that of the Pi.  If you don't see this route, you can add it manually:

```
sudo ip route add 10.100.0.0/30 via 10.100.0.1 dev eth0
```

Again, that last `via` address should be that of the local Pi, not the other one. You should now be able to ping back and forth and do anything else IP networking wise.

---

1. If you didn't boot up with that `denyinterfaces` set, you should restart `dhcpd` (`systemctl restart dhcpcd`), check if there is an a non link local address set already (`ip a`), and remove that if necessary first (`sudo ip addr del x.x.x.x dev eth0`), but I don't think there will be.  A "link local" address begins `169.254.x.x`, don't worry about that.